# User records created by devise invite gets deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) invitable module in one of my application. I have a report feature in which a user(i.e sender) can share his own details in a form of a report with other users(i.e. receiver). The sender needs to input the email address of the receiver in an form. We search for the receiver's record in our users table and if there is no entry then we use devise [invite feature](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) to create a record for him/her and update the association for share details in share_information table. The receiver gets an email with a link to set his/her password. Everything works well if the receiver uses that link to set his/her password and claim his/her account. But if the user does not use the link to set password and tries to sign up instead then problem arises. In such scenario the earlier record for that user gets deleted and a new record is generated with a new user id. The association breaks as the share_information has association with the earlier user_id. How do I solve the problem and why does devise deletes the user? I did not find information about such event in devise gem documents. I did not add code as I think it is not a code problem. Though I could add it if somebody needs to refer. Any help or suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, devise user works in a certain way. If a user is invited and he does not claim the account but tries to sign up then devise just deletes the previous user and creates a new record. It makes sense too in a certain perspective. Anyways I had to solve the issue so the invited user was generated with a black password. I inserted a devise friendly token password in the record and then the devise would not delete the user. It would give a notice of user already exist.

```
user = User.invite!({:email => user[:email], :first_name => user[:first_name], :last_name => user[:last_name], :phone_number => user[:phone]}, current_user)
user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
user.save!
```